# Connecting a Django project that is hosted on a Virtual Machine with Nginx and Gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm new to deploying applications. Currently, I'm hosting my Django project on an Ubuntu virtual machine with IP address 192.168.xxx.xxx. It is hosted on a physical service with public IP address of 202.xxx.xxx.xxx (using port 8080).

I have gunicorn and nginx installed and incorporated, and they're running properly as `sudo systemctl status gunicorn` and `sudo systemctl status nginx` show that they're running with no errors. However, when I try to access the public IP address 202.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080, I'm getting the default Nginx page.

As for how I setup my gunicorn and nginx, I followed the guide posted here:

https://medium.com/@muhammadali_12976/deploying-django-on-a-local-virtual-machine-virtualbox-with-nginx-and-gunicorn-369f70937913

Here's the gunicorn.socket file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/home/myProject/myProject.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Here's the gunicorn.service file:

```
[Unit]

Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]

User=myUserName

Group=www-data

WorkingDirectory=/home/myProject

ExecStart=/home/myProject/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/myProject/myProject.sock core.wsgi:application

[Install]

WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here's the contents of my /etc/nginx/sites-available/myProject file

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.168.xxx.xxx;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/myProject;
    }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/myProject/myProject.sock;
    }
}
```

Should I have used the public address in server_name or the IP address of the virtual machine where my Django project is hosted? In addition, I also tried changing the port in nginx file to 8080, but somehow it still does not work.